# AMC 2003 Cut the cube into pieces.

Tags: contest-math, dissection

For each vertex of a cube a plane is constructed through the three vertices which are neighbors of that vertex. Into how many parts do these eight planes dissect the cube?
(A) 9 (B) 13 (C) 21 (D) 27 (E) 24

---

[image: cut the cube]
My answer is 21. I think about each corner. for example , the green corner(with green point), it is cut by the green triangular plane, with the green point, it forms a tetrahedron. This tetrahedron is also cut by other 3 planes. This dissect it into 3+1=4 parts (3 tetrahedron corners and 1 tetrahedron center).
It seems that all the 8 cube corners are cut into 3x8+1x8=32 parts. But each tetrahedron corner part has been counted twice. So there are 3x8/2+1x8=20  parts. Do not forget, after all the dissections, there is 1 part in the cube center.
Therefore, total parts are 20+1=21 parts.
But the official answer is NOT 21 ?!

Comment: I agree that it is 21 - one core octahedron with 8 regular tetrahedra, and 12 tetrahedra along the cube edges.

Comment: Where did you get the "official answer"?

Comment: 21 pieces as shown here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2803706/420432 (I don't consider that other question a duplicate, it just happens to have an answer that is helpful here.)

Comment: @almagest I have the test paper questions and answers. But there are no solutions. The official answer is (A) 9 parts

Comment: Which AMC 2003 question is it? Is it US or Australia? If US is it AMC 8,12 etc?

Comment: @almagest Australia Math Competition 2003 Intermediate, the last question.

Answer (score 0):

[image: cube cutting]
My answer is 21. I think about each corner. for example , the green corner(with green point), it is cut by the green triangular plane, with the green point, it forms a tetrahedron. This tetrahedron is also cut by other 3 planes. This dissect it into 3+1=4 parts (3 tetrahedron corners and 1 tetrahedron center).
It seems that all the 8 cube corners are cut into 3x8+1x8=32 parts. But each tetrahedron corner part has been counted twice. So there are 3x8/2+1x8=20  parts. Do not forget, after all the dissections, there is 1 part(octahedron) in the cube center.
Therefore, total parts are 20+1=21 parts.